# How can I show data in RDLC in side by side tables?

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I have been tasked with a RDLC report where I have to show data in the table side by side (from a single dataset). Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

I have added a sample image. Hope that helps to understand what I am trying to say.
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZjzQ.png)

Comment: Does it need to be symmetrical? Is the rowcount always the same?  (ex: if there are 16 rows this week but 19 rows next week, does it need to be 8 left & 8 right this week and 10 left & 9 right next week)

Comment: Also, does it need to have the first half left and the second half right? Because it is easier to do odds left and evens right.

Comment: Hey, @tgolisch. Thanks for your attention. The row count doesn't have to be dynamic. It will be fixed (as many rows fits in a single page). When the left side fills up, then the right side of the table will start filling up.
For your 2nd question, yeah, I am afraid it needs to have the first half on left side and the 2nd half on right.

Comment: Okay, those conditions are much easier. Basically, figure out how many rows fit on a page. In your report, set up two tables (left/right). Filter the left one to use rows 1 to N and the right one to use (N+1) to (N*2). Repeat as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure how "alias" the columns, but you could create a query source that left joins the odd rows (starting at row 1, left side), and then join the even rows for the right side.

So, say this table

```
 select ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY HotelName) as  R from tblHotelsA
```

And we get/see this:

| ID | FirstName | LastName | HotelName | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | Albertz | zoo | My Cool | 1 |
| 87 | Rod | Grey | Park Place Lodge | 2 |
| 23 | Maxine | Dehart | Ramada Lodge | 3 |
| 26 | Sean | Braid | Sandman Inn | 4 |
| 29 | Ron | xx | Super 8 | 5 |
| 69 | Reservations | Test Edit | Swiss Village | 6 |

So, 6 rows,

but, if we execute this query:

```
WITH MyRows as 
(
select ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY HotelName) as  R from tblHotelsA
)
select * FROM MyRows AS MyRowsLEFT
LEFT JOIN 
(
select * FROM MyRows AS MyRowsRIGHT
WHERE MyRowsRIGHT.R % 2 = 0 
) 
MyRowsRIGHT2 ON MyRowsLEFT.R + 1 = MyRowsRIGHT2.R
WHERE MyRowsLEFT.R % 2 = 1
ORDER BY myRowsLEFT.HotelName
```

We get this:

| ID | FirstName | LastName | HotelName | R | ID | FirstName | LastName | HotelName | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | Albertz | zoo | My Cool | 1 | 87 | Rod | Grey | Park Place Lodge | 2 |
| 23 | Maxine | Dehart | Ramada Lodge | 3 | 26 | Sean | Braid | Sandman Inn | 4 |
| 29 | Ron | xx | Super 8 | 5 | 69 | Reservations | Test Edit | Swiss Village | 6 |

So, we now have a single data set that puts the odd rows on left side, and the right side has the even rows.

So, then the above query could be used as "one" data source for the report.